# Load data infile gives me an access denied permissions error. How else can I import a text file into my table in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to import a text file that contains data separated by , . I read on several sources that most people use, "LOAD DATA INFILE". So, I figured it would work for me too.

I get this permissions error however when I do so. I ran this command and here is what I got:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/public_html/nyccrash.txt' INTO TABLE nyccrash;
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1045(28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I read on some other threads that all I had to do was include the full file path and I did but it still didn't work.

Is there another way to import a text file into my table in my database? Using SQL or PHP.

EDIT:

I found this command I can use:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$handle = fopen("nyccrash.txt", "r");
echo("<table>");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo("<tr>\r\n");
    foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
        echo("\t<td>$val</td>\r\n");
    }
    echo("</tr>\r\n");
}
echo("</table>");
fclose($handle);
```

?>

That allows me to read the data and create a table and print it. I can also use the INSERT INTO table sql command after using the above to collect the data but I'm not sure how to insert the values into the table. That is, loop through the values for insertion. My data in the txt file doesn't not contain the attributes or headers of what's contained. So... I'm a little confused on how to sort the data into the right columns.

Comment: "Access denied" seems pretty clear (and shouldn't have to do with the INFILE at all?) How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Congratulations on 200k. Don't they send out SO sweatshirts for that milestone?

Comment: @Michael thanks! I think you get an atrocious painting. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/

Comment: @Pekka, I am connecting via ssh.

Comment: @Pekka웃 [Eric Lippert must not have been so lucky](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/03/podcast-45-keeping-it-sharp/) as to receive a masterwork such as that.

Comment: Ok, but how are you connecting to the *database?* What credentials are you using, can you run queries in it? This likely has to do with the way you connect to the database, not with the IMPORT command you're running.

Comment: @Michael yeah, I think that was a one-off. As it happens though, I did receive an offer for some nice swag a minute ago! Cool.

Comment: I'm connecting to the database by "connect database" command. I can run queries in it (e.g. Select * FROM table). I'm using credentials from mysql.

Comment: So you can do a `SELECT * FROM nyccrash;` without problems? That'd be weird.

Comment: Yeah I am! It says it's an empty set because I wasn't able to import any data. I think maybe I should just use php for this. I can use the getcsvfile command and insert into table sql query but I'm not sure how to get the values for that command from the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made sure I gave my txt file permissions: `chmod 711`

Then I used   `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'nyccrash.txt' INTO TABLE nyccrash FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';`  and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In order to load data via `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` you need two things:

1. [**FILE privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file). Have a superuser run `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';`.
2. Set [**local_infile**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) to 1 in `my.cnf`. To avoid having to restart mysql, have a superuser run `SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;`.

CAVEAT : Both of these things would  be deemed a security breach.

Answer (score 0):

IF you gonna do this a few times, you can mount a sql query by importing data into Excel, and use concat to mount the sql lines, and copy/paste to the client and execute. It's not very usefull for lots of tables. If so, it's not hard to use php to upload a csv file and populate the table.

Comment: Could you direct me to a php tutorial on this subject? Thank you. I found documentation on how to read a csv file but nothing about importing it into a table.

Comment: Actually, I found this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp but I'm not sure how to insert the values... Thanks again!

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3...) VALUES (v1, v2, v3...). Is that you cant get?

Comment: My table contains 12,000 records of data. I don't want to manually insert the values. How do I loop through the values?

Comment: import the data to excel, after last col put something like this: =CONCAT("INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (";A1;",";B1;",";C1;");") and copy until last line. I dont know if u can copy/past 12000 records, bus you can save the result as a sql file, and execute at the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
// Connect to Database
$db_Host = "";
$db_Username = "";
$db_Password = "";
mysql_connect($db_Host,$db_Username,$db_Password) or die("MySQL - Connection Error");
mysql_select_db($db_Database) or die("MySQL - Cannot Select Database");

mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/username/public_html/Database.txt' INTO TABLE yourtablename") or die("MySQL - Query Error - " . MySQL_Error());

//MySQL is automatically disconnected from when PHP ends.
```